# Solspace User password reset not working

Tags: solspace, solspace-user, forgot-password

The link that gets email when someone forgets their password does not work.  YOu get a page not found error.

EE 2.7.1 and User 3.4.5

User is up to date so not sure why this is not working.  Anyone out there running in to the same issues?

Comment: The problem is most likely that the forgot password template isn't set up - but without seeing some code it'll be almost impossible to trouble shoot.

Comment: Are you using the FocusLab config setup? Add the URL that is 404'ing to your question.

Comment: isn't the forgot password template there by default?  I am not even sure where to start looking.  I am using the default config set up. (no focuslab) and default htaccess file to remove index.php.  Member trigger word is member.

RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

Answer (score 1):

solved.  the member profile theme was incorrectly set

Answer (score 0):

Starting with EE 2.6, the reset password routine works differently compared to pre-2.6 version. Instead of being sent a password reset link after filling out a "**forgot password**" form, followed by an automatically generated new password by email, users receive a link by email to visit a page on EE with a "**password reset**" form to reset their password themselves.

As of this writing, User doesn't have a "password reset" form available, and is therefore not involved after submitting the "forgot password" form. In consequence, the password reset notification email is generated by native EE, and the link's URL points to a native EE member template.

If you have issues with the emailed URL, this would an EE issue to resolve. Check your EE settings, .htaccess file, and member trigger word (member preferences), as potential places places for EE not being able to read its own member templates.

Comment: Can we assume that Solspace is working on a new User template tag to circumvent EE's new reset password form?

Comment: The feature has been noted and we plan on adding the feature. However, we do not have an ETA for when this would be implemented.

Comment: Any update on when a User-powered password reset template would be available? The native EE password reset form is the only ugly EE page I cannot customize and it drives me crazy.